# Multi-shell application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, prism-4, region-management

I am new to Prism.

1. Imagin a scenario where you want to develop a multi-region application, but there should are many types of screens and I want those regions to be in one screen only, whereas, for instance in the HomePage which is the application map (like in QuickBooks, see image bellow), there should be no regions, and the whole layout should be different.
2. Also I want that the application should be available for registered users only; unregistered users are automatically forwarded to the LoginView, and they're not supposed to see the regions etc.

How are these two aspects achieved?

[image: QuickBooks home page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am going to implement the entire application using [View-Based Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430881%28PandP.40%29.aspx).